# Best java library for POJO mapping with MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, morphia, jongo

I've bean using Morphia for some time (2+ years) now but not much has happens with the library to incorporate the new features in MongoDB 2.6+ version. Looking at the activity on Github, not much has happen since early semptember and I am start to wonder if there are better library that includes the new features of MongoDB 2.6

Here are some of the features that I am currently missing in Morphia;

- Wrapping and handling GeoJson object for making geospatial queries for spherical intersections with haystack indexes etc.
- Polymorphism handling of Java classes for storing similar objects in one container, with the possibility for specific objects types
- Text searching in verbose objects with a lot of text

I've bean looking at Spring Mongo DB, but I don't use Spring as a framework. I use standard Java EE 6, so not to keen to add the Spring stack to my project. Jongo library looks simple and relays on Jackson for marshalling object. But it is more of a text query interface than I would like and I don't know how good the geospatial features are.

Does anyone know or have inside info if the issues stated above will be fixed in the near future?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not associated with MongoDB or the development of either the Java driver or Morphia, so this is just a personal opinion:

Yes, Morphia's development has (again) stalled. However, I'm currently hoping that the development focus is on the Java driver version 3, see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/commits/3.0.x

There have been plans to port some functionality to the Java driver, but I'm not sure what the current status is. I'd hope that Morphia's development is waiting for changes in the driver and it will pick up speed once version 3 is out.

Comment: Thank for some insight info on the development. There is now a considerable gap what morphia offers compared to the functionality in MongoDB. But there is slim hope that anything will happen with the library, due to the slow pace of change lately. My search is on.